# Garbage collection eats status item

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, garbage-collection

I turned on garbage collection (objective-c 2.0) and the image for the status item disappeared when I restarted my application.  I am manually memory managing the image and status item.

This application works normal when garbage collection is off (i.e. the status item doesn't disappear.)  Is there a way to make the garbage collection not collect specific variables or should I turn it off completely? When turning on garbage collection, my app's memory drops from 100mb to 2mb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you "manually managing the memory of the image and status item"?  If you are using `release` and `retain`, they are actually ignored under GC.

Under GC, objects stick around if (a) you have a strong reference to them in GC scanned memory *or* you (b) `CFRetain` them.

Answer (score 1):

Just keep a reference to it as an instance variable of some object e.g. the controller of the view it appears in.

Comment: Can you show me and example of how I could do that?  That would be good :)